# Find an infimum of the function on a set

Tags: supremum-and-infimum

I came across a nasty task which includes infimum of a function on a set and I am really confused about it. Main confusion is the two arguments of the function. It's not a problem for me in finding infimums and supremums of sets, but here I am just stuck.

Function: 
$$
f(x) = (\cos(x^2+y^2))^{\large \cos(x^2+y^2)}
$$
Need to find the infimum of this function on a set $E$:
$$
E=\left\{(x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^2|x^2+y^2 < \frac{\pi}{2}\right\}
$$

Comment: Hint : let $z= x^2+y^2$

Answer (score 2):

Hint: consider the function $\tilde{f}(\varrho) = (\cos \varrho ) ^{\cos \varrho}$ defined on the interval $[0,\pi/2)$.

Comment: So then I could take a derivative of this function and examine it on the interval, right?